# Best practice when adding custom method to Array (Built-in object)

Tags: javascript, node.js, javascript-objects, node-modules

I have created a [node module](https://github.com/joakim5937x/inverse-slice) with a couple of custom methods for arrays and strings.

First I just used it like a regular module and got the functions from a `require` like this:

#### Alt 1.

```
const invSlice = require('inverted-slice');
let arr1 = [1,2,3,4];
invSlice.iSlice(arr, start, stop);
```

This works but it would be nicer to call `iSlice` as a method on the `Array` object. I solved this by adding the following code in my library:

```
Array.prototype.iSlice = iSliceBuiltin; // iSliceBuiltin is my function
```

And the method can now be used like:

#### Alt 2.

```
require('inverted-slice');
let arr1 = [1,2,3,4];
arr1.iSlice(start, stop);
```

Which I think is nicer then **Alt 1**.

### Question

My question is if there is any best practice or guidelines to follow when adding custom methods like in **Alt 2** to built-in Objects like `Array` or `String` ?

Comment: I think most people would say that "best practice" is to *not* add methods to built-in objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extending built-in prototypes has always triggered debates, and I think we can conclude it is *not* considered best practice.

On the other hand it is indeed nice if you can call these custom methods as object methods instead of plain functions.

You might consider a wrapper function that will return an Array instance that has the extra methods defined for it: i.e., not on the prototype, but on the Array instance itself.

Your module could look like this:

```
function iArray(arr) {
    return Object.assign([], arr || [], {
        iSlice: iSliceBuiltin,
        iSplice: iSpliceBuiltin
    });
}

// ... your module functions come here, but excluding the changes to the Array prototype

module.exports = {
    iArray
}
```

Then you would use it like this:

```
const iArray = require('inverted-slice');

let arr1 = iArray([1,2,3,4]); // enrich array with extra methods
let result = arr1.iSlice(0, 1);
```

To allow chaining, you could change the `return` statement in `iSliceSpliceHelper` to:

```
return iArray(newArr);
```

So, now you can write:

```
let arr1 = iArray([1,2,3,4]); // enrich array with extra methods
let result = arr1.iSlice(0, 1).iSlice(1, 2);
```

Existing libraries might implement your alternative 1 (e.g. [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/)), but many also go for something like I propose here. See for instance [Sugar](https://sugarjs.com/quickstart/#/Usage) (`new Sugar.Array([1,2,3])`), or [Lazy](http://danieltao.com/lazy.js/) (`Lazy([1,2,3])`).

Answer (score 1):

In small doses I think it's not that big of a deal to use Alt 2, but I believe that over usage can create problems. If I remember correctly, they had to completely redo Cut The Rope due to performance problems that I believe stemmed largely in part from prototype extensions. You may also want to consider posting this on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

A couple references:

http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/104320/why-is-extending-the-dom-built-in-object-prototypes-a-bad-idea

Comment: You need alt 1 if you don't want to add the function to the Array.prototype. If it is a bad practice to modify bultin-objects, and that is my question!

Comment: Oh, my eyes were deceiving me. I could've swore they were both being extended on `Array`, and it had me confused as to why someone would do that.

Comment: That first article has some useful information, but adding methods to `Array.prototype` isn't extending the *DOM*.

Comment: The primary issues people have seem to be the same for both DOM and built-in objects: potential collision and browser compatibility. The first article has some pretty detailed explanations on what those are and they do apply to both.